# PyErr_Print after PyErr_Restore

Tags: python, c, traceback

I have already extracted what I want using PyErr_Fetch. Now, I would like to restore everything back in order to use PyErr_Print. My code is basically this:

```
   PyObject *type, *value, *traceback;
   PyErr_Fetch(&type, &value, &traceback);
   ...   
   PyErr_Restore(type, value, traceback);
   PyErr_Print();
```

I got an exception SIGSEGV during PyErr_Print() pointing to traceback.c

Should I update the reference count before using PyErr_Print()? I've tried to increase without success.